# Best alternative to wrapfig?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, wrapfig

I'm working on a textbook with many figures, and I've been using `wrapfig` to place ones that are less than a full-page wide. However, the results are often just plain awful. Reading around, I was surprised to learn that `wrapfig` doesn't actually determine and use the optimal placement like most things in LaTeX do, and that it's essentially obligatory to go over your whole document in its near final form and manually move things around to fix figures wrapped in `wrapfig`. That ain't the LaTeX way! And as this package was last updated in 2003, as far as I can tell, it won't ever be improved.

So what is the best alternative to `wrapfig`?

Comment: A two-column book. Not only allow a nice placement of figures with 50% widths, but also more readable text (fewer characters per line and margin is always in the same place).

Comment: Have you tried `minipage` or `subfigure`?  Or even some combination?  I had some success with figure placement in a proposal with these when `wrapfig` was not cutting it.

Comment: For better or worse, it has to be single column. As to subfigure, it was abandoned in 2002 and is officially listed as deprecated. And subfig breaks hyperref and its development stopped in 2005.

Comment: @GilWilliams instead of `subfig` or `subfigure`, you can use `subcaption`. Also, while this is even more manual than `wrapfig` I prefer `insbox`. But this is really 100% manual placement.

Comment: @Skillmon The `subcaption` examples I've been able to find have their code blocks wrapped inside `subfig`, `subfigure`, etc. How can `subcaption` *replace* these packages? Also, thanks for the `insbox` suggestion, but my goal is to find a LaTeX figure placement package that actually uses LaTeX's brilliant layout logic.

Comment: @GilWilliams there is no ready-made solution for real floating figures/tables that are inserted like you want it. The `subcaption` package provides the `subfigure` environment you see in the code blocks. It doesn't require the `subfigure` or `subfig` packages (and in fact is incompatible with them).

Comment: You might take a look at the `hvfloat` package.  It offers many options not provided by other packages.  An [overview](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-3/tb132voss-hvfloat.pdf) was published in TUGboat 42:3. but it will be available only to members until issue 43:1 is published.  But it *is* available on CTAN and in TeX Live, and has an extensive user manual.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a convincing answer... but note that ConTeXt deals with wrapped figures pretty nicely (even when lists are included, new pages...). Unfortunately, it diverged quite considerably from LaTeX so you need to change your workflow completely, and is not yet as famous as LaTeX. To learn how to use it, read more [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Documentation).

[image]

**MWE** (compile with `context yourfile.tex`):

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[ipsum]

\starttext

\ipsum[before=\blank,after=\blank]

\placefigure[left][fig:logo]{This is an example of a logo.}{\externalfigure[https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/cat-551554_960_720.jpg]}

\ipsum[before=\blank,after=\blank]

\placefigure[right][fig:logo]{}{\externalfigure[https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/cat-551554_960_720.jpg]}

\ipsum[before=\blank,after=\blank]


\placefigure[left][fig:logo]{}{\externalfigure[https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/11/30/14/11/cat-551554_960_720.jpg]}

\startitemize
\item Hello
\item My
\item Friend
\item Hello
\item My
\item Friend
\item Hello
\item My
\item Friend
\item Hello
\item My
\item Friend
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```